# MySQL SELECT query: i want show duplicated entries

Tags: mysql, select

Example

My query is:

```
SELECT code_CAT FROM categories WHERE id_code IN(14,14,14,14);
```

output is:

```
53724
```

Only one row.

Instead I want this output:

```
53724
53724
53724
53724
```

How can I achieve this? I want this because I need to use the records on an Excel Spreadsheet.

Comment: I saw a good example in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

But I feel, your question is not complete to give you an answer. 

Can you paste the output of following SQL query into question:

    SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id_code IN(14,14,14,14);

Comment: There's only one row returned because there is only one row in the table `categories` where code_CAT has the value 14.  Repeating that same id_code value in the `IN` doesn't change that.  I don't follow why, if there is only one such row in the table, you want it repeated four times.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need it (I don't get why though), you can do

```
SELECT code_CAT 
FROM categories a
INNER JOIN 
(
  select 14 as id_code
  UNION ALL
  select 14
  UNION ALL
  select 14
  UNION ALL
  select 14
)b ON (a.id_code = b.id_code)
```